# Is it right to say "What time is it?" and "What day is it?" when asking about the day and the time of an event?

Tags: questions, time

If there's an event yet to come and two people talking to each other about it, if one of them doesn't know about the day and the time, can he ask (**What day is it?**) and (**What time is it?**)? Isn't it misundrestood that he is asking about the day and the time of now?

> Example
>
> A: There's a game this month.
>
> B: **What time is it?**
>
> A: It's at 8:30 P.M.
>
> B: **What day is it?**
>
> A: On the fifth.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse the name of a verb tense with the way we use it to talk about time.  For example, present tense does not always refer to present time:

> - Your appointment is tomorrow.
> - He goes in for surgery next Saturday.
> - The story runs in next Sunday's *Post*.
> - Q: How do we know it's dinnertime?  A: When the dinner bell rings at six o'clock.

The verbs "is," "goes," "runs," "do," and "rings" are all present simple, but they refer here to future time.

Here is another example:

> John: I'm going to have a party.
>
> Jane: *When is it?*

The present tense of the verb "to be" is often used to talk about the time of things that will happen in the future.

References:

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_sys-tense-time.htm

http://www.bergen.edu/ELRC/guidemxtnsex.htm

Comment: Another question: Which one is right?
1.There's a game **in** this month.

or

2.There's a game this month.

Comment: @Reza : 2. There's a game this month.

Answer (score 0):

Though it correct to answer with *what time [...]* I would not use the verb form of *to be* in this context.

> - What time does it take place?
> - At what time does it take place?
> - What time does it take place at?

Same goes with *day*

I feel *What time is it?* would rather be understood as *What time is it at this exact moment?*

Comment: Agreed. The unambiguous question to me would be "when is it?"   I would always take "what day/time is it?" to mean now, not a future event.

Comment: So if we don't take the pronoun **it**, it would be correct to use the noun itself: "What time's **the game**?" or "What day is **the game**?" The question is not whether to use "to be" verb or not. The question is that if we can use a pronoun instead of nouns or not?

Comment: I would consider it correct, yes. And no, the question was never if _to be_ was right in the above case. I just took up the OP's wording and therefore also mentioned _What time is it?_